# Getting versionCode and VersionName from Google Play

Tags: java, android, google-play

I am looking for a way how to get app versionCode and VersionName from google play with package name via java app in PC.
I have seen: https://androidquery.appspot.com/ but it not working anymore and also https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/ started to making problems and also stopped working, and it requer device ID.
Can you help me with some simple solution or API for this?
Very important, i need **versionCode and VersionName** and VersionName is relatively easy to get by parsing html google play app site. The versionCode is very important.

Comment: Do you want this for your apps? Or any app at play store?

Comment: For my apps at the company I currently work at. Each app is signed with different key. So I its like actually for any app at play store..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no official Google Play API, Playstore uses an internal protobuf API which is not documented and not open. IMHO, you could :

- use an open source library that reverse engineer the API
- scrap apk download sites that have already extracted this information (most likely via the same protobuf Google Play API)

Note that there is a [Google Play developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/) but you can't list your apks, versions, apps. It's essentially used to manage the app distribution, reviews, edits etc..

### Google play internal API

#### [play-store-api Java library](https://github.com/yeriomin/play-store-api)

This library uses Google Play Store protobuf API (undocumented and closed API) and requires an email/password to generate a token that can be reused to play with the API :

```
GplaySearch googlePlayInstance = new GplaySearch();

DetailsResponse response = googlePlayInstance.getDetailResponse("user@gmail.com",
        "password", "com.facebook.katana");

AppDetails appDetails = response.getDocV2().getDetails().getAppDetails();

System.out.println("version name : " + appDetails.getVersionString());
System.out.println("version code : " + appDetails.getVersionCode());
```

with this method :

```
public DetailsResponse getDetailResponse(String email,
                                         String password,
                                         String packageName) throws IOException, ApiBuilderException {
    // A device definition is required to log in
    // See resources for a list of available devices
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getSystemResourceAsStream("device-honami" +
                ".properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("device-honami.properties not found");
        return null;
    }
    PropertiesDeviceInfoProvider deviceInfoProvider = new PropertiesDeviceInfoProvider();
    deviceInfoProvider.setProperties(properties);
    deviceInfoProvider.setLocaleString(Locale.ENGLISH.toString());

    // Provide valid google account info
    PlayStoreApiBuilder builder = new PlayStoreApiBuilder()
            .setDeviceInfoProvider(deviceInfoProvider)
            .setHttpClient(new OkHttpClientAdapter())
            .setEmail(email)
            .setPassword(password);
    GooglePlayAPI api = builder.build();

    // We are logged in now
    // Save and reuse the generated auth token and gsf id,
    // unless you want to get banned for frequent relogins
    api.getToken();
    api.getGsfId();

    // API wrapper instance is ready
    return api.details(packageName);
}
```

`device-honami.properties` is device property file that is required to identify device characteristics. You have some device.properties file sample [here](https://github.com/yeriomin/play-store-api/tree/master/src/main/resources)

The `OkHttpClientAdapter` can be found [here](https://github.com/yeriomin/play-store-api/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/yeriomin/playstoreapi/OkHttpClientAdapter.java)

Dependencies used to run this example :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.yeriomin:play-store-api:0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
}
```

### Scrap third part apk download sites

#### http://apk-dl.com

You could get the version name & version code from http://apk-dl.com (of course unofficial) by scraping the page with [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) for the required package name :

```
String packageName = "com.facebook.katana";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://apk-dl.com/" + packageName).get();
Elements data = doc.select(".file-list .mdl-menu__item");

if (data.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println("full text : " + data.get(0).text());
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\s+\\((\\d+)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data.get(0).text());
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("version name : " + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("version code : " + matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

#### https://apkpure.com

Another possibility is scrapping https://apkpure.com :

```
String packageName = "com.facebook.katana";

Elements data = Jsoup.connect("https://apkpure.com/search?q=" + packageName)
        .userAgent("Mozilla")
        .get().select(".search-dl .search-title a");

if (data.size() > 0) {

    Elements data2 = Jsoup.connect("https://apkpure.com" + data.attr("href"))
            .userAgent("Mozilla")
            .get().select(".faq_cat dd p");

    if (data2.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(data2.get(0).text());

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Version:\\s+(.*)\\s+\\((\\d+)\\)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data2.get(0).text());
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("version name : " + matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println("version code : " + matcher.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```

#### https://api-apk.evozi.com

Also, https://api-apk.evozi.com has an internal JSON api but :

- sometimes it doesn't work (return `Ops, APK Downloader got access denied when trying to download`) mostly for non popular app
- it has mechanism in place against scraping bot (random token generated in JS with a random variable name)

The following is returning the version name and code with https://api-apk.evozi.com FWIW :

```
String packageName = "com.facebook.katana";

String data = Jsoup.connect("https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader")
        .userAgent("Mozilla")
        .execute().body();

String token = "";
String time = "";

Pattern varPattern = Pattern.compile("dedbadfbadc:\\s+(\\w+),");
Pattern timePattern = Pattern.compile("t:\\s+(\\w+),");

Matcher varMatch = varPattern.matcher(data);
Matcher timeMatch = timePattern.matcher(data);

if (varMatch.find()) {
    Pattern tokenPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*var\\s*" + varMatch.group(1) + "\\s*=\\s*'(.*)'.*");
    Matcher tokenMatch = tokenPattern.matcher(data);

    if (tokenMatch.find()) {
        token = tokenMatch.group(1);
    }
}

if (timeMatch.find()) {
    time = timeMatch.group(1);
}

HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api-apk.evozi.com/download");

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("t", time));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("afedcfdcbdedcafe", packageName));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dedbadfbadc", token));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fetch", "false"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
JsonObject result = element.getAsJsonObject();

if (result.has("version") && result.has("version_code")) {
    System.out.println("version name : " + result.get("version").getAsString());
    System.out.println("version code : " + result.get("version_code").getAsInt());
} else {
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

### Implementation

You could implement it on a backend of yours that communicates directly with your Java application, this way you could maintain the process of retrieving version code/name if one of the above method fails.

If you are only interested in your own apps, a cleaner solution would be :

- to set up a backend which will store all your current app version name / version code
- all developer/publisher in your company could share a publish task (gradle task) which will use the [Google Play developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/) to publish apk and that gradle task would include a call to your backend to store the version code / version name entry when the app is published. The main goal would be to automate the whole publication with storage of the app metadata on your side.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, but is there any way to do so without using those 3RD party sites, or maybe you know how they do it?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the first solution worked perfectly with our needs. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using JSoup, we can alternatively do pattern matching for getting the app version from playStore.

To match the latest pattern from google playstore ie 
     `<div class="BgcNfc">Current Version</div><span class="htlgb"><div><span class="htlgb">X.X.X</span></div>`
we first have to match the above node sequence and then from above sequence get the version value. Below is the code snippet for same:

```
    private String getAppVersion(String patternString, String inputString) {
        try{
            //Create a pattern
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
            if (null == pattern) {
                return null;
            }

            //Match the pattern string in provided string
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
            if (null != matcher && matcher.find()) {
                return matcher.group(1);
            }

        }catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    private String getPlayStoreAppVersion(String appUrlString) {
        final String currentVersion_PatternSeq = "<div[^>]*?>Current\\sVersion</div><span[^>]*?>(.*?)><div[^>]*?>(.*?)><span[^>]*?>(.*?)</span>";
        final String appVersion_PatternSeq = "htlgb\">([^<]*)</s";
        String playStoreAppVersion = null;

        BufferedReader inReader = null;
        URLConnection uc = null;
        StringBuilder urlData = new StringBuilder();

        final URL url = new URL(appUrlString);
        uc = url.openConnection();
        if(uc == null) {
           return null;
        }
        uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
        inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
        if (null != inReader) {
            String str = "";
            while ((str = inReader.readLine()) != null) {
                           urlData.append(str);
            }
        }

        // Get the current version pattern sequence 
        String versionString = getAppVersion (currentVersion_PatternSeq, urlData.toString());
        if(null == versionString){ 
            return null;
        }else{
            // get version from "htlgb">X.X.X</span>
            playStoreAppVersion = getAppVersion (appVersion_PatternSeq, versionString);
        }

        return playStoreAppVersion;
    }
```

I got this solved through this. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup takes too long, its inefficient, for short easy way with pattermatching:

```
public class PlayStoreVersionChecker {

public String playStoreVersion = "0.0.0";

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

private String execute(String url) throws IOException {
    okhttp3.Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}

public String getPlayStoreVersion() {
    try {
        String html = execute("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + APPIDHERE!!! + "&hl=en");
        Pattern blockPattern = Pattern.compile("Current Version.*([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)</span>");
        Matcher blockMatch = blockPattern.matcher(html);
        if(blockMatch.find()) {
            Pattern versionPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+");
            Matcher versionMatch = versionPattern.matcher(blockMatch.group(0));
            if(versionMatch.find()) {
                playStoreVersion = versionMatch.group(0);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return playStoreVersion;
}


}
```

Comment: What is 'okhttp3'?

Comment: @DeboraCarnevali okhttp3 is a android library for http requests, very simple one at that

Comment: What should I write as APPID? Is this app's package name?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Store {

    private Document document;
    private final static String baseURL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public Store(String packageName) {
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect(baseURL + packageName).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0").get();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return document.select("h1.AHFaub > span").text();
    }

    public String getDeveloper() {
        return document.selectFirst("span.UAO9ie > a").text();
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        Elements elements = document.select("span.UAO9ie > a");
        for (Element element : elements) {
            if (element.hasAttr("itemprop")) {
                return element.text();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return document.select("div.xSyT2c > img").attr("src");
    }

    public String getBigIcon() {
        return document.select("div.xSyT2c > img").attr("srcset").replace(" 2x", "");
    }

    public List<String> getScreenshots() {
        List<String> screenshots = new ArrayList<>();
        Elements img = document.select("div.u3EI9e").select("button.Q4vdJd").select("img");
        for (Element src : img) {
            if (src.hasAttr("data-src")) {
                screenshots.add(src.attr("data-src"));
            } else {
                screenshots.add(src.attr("src"));
            }
        }
        return screenshots;
    }

    public List<String> getBigScreenshots() {
        List<String> screenshots = new ArrayList<>();
        Elements img = document.select("div.u3EI9e").select("button.Q4vdJd").select("img");
        for (Element src : img) {
            if (src.hasAttr("data-src")) {
                screenshots.add(src.attr("data-srcset").replace(" 2x", ""));
            } else {
                screenshots.add(src.attr("srcset").replace(" 2x", ""));
            }
        }
        return screenshots;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return document.select("div.DWPxHb > span").text();
    }

    public String getRatings() {
        return document.select("div.BHMmbe").text();
    }
}
```

**Imports**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
```

This script will return

Category (Personalization for example)
Developer Name
App Icon
App Name
Screenshots (Thumbnail and Full preview)
Description

You can also check the full source code [here](https://github.com/arghadasofficial/Scrappers/blob/master/src/argha/scrapper/Store.java)